# How to mimic Org-Mode with cell dingbats?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, notebooks, cells

I love using [org-mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGeFC.png) to organize my to-do lists, the functionality is amazing, but it suffers from being stuck inside the emacs terminal...

I'm hoping to replicate some basic features into a notebook, specially checklists. I'm looking for something like this, where the cell dingbats are checkboxes and subitems get dynamically tallied:

[image]

So my question is:

**How to make counters in cells that update based on the count of the checkboxes of their subitems?**

Answer (score 5):

It is unclear whether the checklist reflects the total number of boxes checked or the position of the boxes. For example if you only has the second box checked do you want to see [1/2] or [2/2]?

Having said that here is something quick to try:

```
x = {False, False};

CellPrint@
 TextCell["Tasks", "Subsection", ShowStringCharacters -> False]
CellPrint@
 TextCell[Text@
   Row[{Dynamic@Row[{"[", Total@Boole@x, "/", Length[x], "]"}], 
     "Checklist"}, Spacer[5]], "Item", ShowStringCharacters -> False]
CellPrint@
 TextCell[Text@Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[x[[1]]]], "task a"}, Spacer[5]], 
  "Subitem", ShowStringCharacters -> False]
CellPrint@
 TextCell[Text@Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[x[[2]]]], "task b"}, Spacer[5]], 
  "Subitem", ShowStringCharacters -> False]
```

[image]

If you want to make this part of the cell dingbat rather than in the actual cell then:

```
CellPrint@
 TextCell[Text@Row[{"Checklist"}, Spacer[5]], "Item", 
  ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
  CellDingbat -> 
   ToBoxes@Text@
     Row[{Style["\[FilledSmallSquare]", Alignment -> Baseline, 
        RGBColor[0.8, 0.043, 0.008]], 
       Dynamic@Row[{"[", Total@Boole@x, "/", Length[x], "]"}]}]]
```

...but I think it is formatted better as is.

**Edit**

```
chewFood[numberOfCheckBoxes_] := Module[{x},
  x = ConstantArray[False, numberOfCheckBoxes];
  CellPrint@
   TextCell["Tasks", "Subsection", ShowStringCharacters -> False]; 
  CellPrint@
   TextCell[
    Text@Row[{Dynamic@Row[{"[", Total@Boole@x, "/", Length[x], "]"}], 
       "Checklist"}, Spacer[5]], "Item", 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False];
  CellPrint@
     TextCell[
      Text@Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[x[[#]]]], 
         "task " <> CharacterRange["a", "z"][[#]]}, Spacer[5]], 
      "Subitem", ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
      ShowGroupOpener -> False] & /@ Range[numberOfCheckBoxes];
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: The ordering doesn't matter, if you only have the second box checked, it's still 1/2 total. Also, if one wants to quickly add more item cells the label would change to 1/n...

Comment: if the ordering doesn't matter then the above is ok?

Comment: Yes, but it's not dynamically counting the cells underneath... so if i copy past task b into a task c, the Checklist should have [x/3] not [x/2]...

Comment: Did you change x from {False,False} to {False,False,False}`? No offense but you have a 4K rep and need to contribute as well! The answer was intended to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I honestly don't know how to achieve what I want - and it might not be possible... I'm not looking for a function that I have to re-execute, but a "dynamic cell style" for which option+return would duplicate and update everything appropriately. Sorry if the question was too vague!

Comment: To fully automate it you would probably need to implement a cell counter and just have a dynamic cell count. Maybe a few other things as well but I don't have time to do all that.